# AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'tunes_list'

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am attempting to create an app that allows me to generate a tune for a game I play. But regardless, my goal is to save and load data from a sqlite3 database. But what is happening instead is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Visual Studio\DRIFT_TUNER\gui.py", line 360, in <module>     
    app = Application(master=root)
  File "d:\Visual Studio\DRIFT_TUNER\gui.py", line 16, in __init__      
    self.populate_list()
  File "d:\Visual Studio\DRIFT_TUNER\gui.py", line 350, in populate_list
    self.tunes_list.delete(0, tk.END)
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'tunes_list'
```

That happens when I call a function `populate_list()` which is this:

```
def populate_list(self):
        self.tunes_list.delete(0, tk.END)
        for row in db.fetch():
            self.tunes_list.insert(tk.END, row)
```

Here are the Pastebins of my two files:

`gui.py`: https://pastebin.com/aJ5qAwtS
`db.py`: https://pastebin.com/mp3RnVK2

`populate_list()` is supposed to clear the text in the Listbox, then fetch data from the database and insert that data row by row into the Listbox. I'm using Python 3.9.5 with tkinter and sqlite3.

Things I've tried:

- Converting all indents to spaces, and all spaces to indents.
- Redeclaring the `tunes_list`

I do not know fully what this error means in the first place so any help would be nice.

Comment: `self.tunes_list` is created in your `load_window` method. Your `load_window` is called only when the button (named `self.load_button`) is pressed. But as soon as you create your `Application` object, you try calling `populate_list` which uses `self.tunes_list`. Therefore, you create a variable only when the button is pressed but try accessing it before that

Comment: @TheLizzard can you post this as an answer, as it worked. I would like to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.tunes_list` is created in your `load_window` method. Your `load_window` is called only when the button (named `self.load_button`) is pressed. But as soon as you create your `Application` object, you try calling `populate_list` which uses `self.tunes_list`. Therefore, you create a variable only when the button is pressed but try accessing it before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding `self.tunes_list = tk.Entry()` in your `__init__` or idk whatever your tunes_list is

Comment: Did you look at the code OP posted? He/She posted it as lists to pastebin. This answer wouldn't work

Comment: @TheLizzard This answer works fine on my computer with the code that I copied from pastebin

Comment: @TheLizzard I wrote the same in other words